# Cómo determinar si una variable es numérica o no con condicionales en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, condiciones, booleano, numberformat

Quiero hacer una función que permita saber si una variable es numérica o no. Retornando true si lo es, y false si no.
El problema está en que no sé cómo hacer para que en el caso que se utilicen variables booleanas retornen false.

```js
function comparar(variable){
  if (isNaN(variable)) 
      return false;
  else 
      return true;
}
console.log(comparar(5)); // true
console.log(comparar("hola")); // false 
console.log(comparar(true)); //true
```

Pero con booleanos me falla porque a fin de cuentas el programa los lee como 0 y 1.
Qué podría hacer?

Comment: Puedes utilizar el método Number.isInteger(123), para validarlo, pero este método solo funciona para los números enteros, ósea que si es un numero decimal, regresará false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IsNaN regresa true si es valor dado es NaN  (No es Un Número), de otro modo, false.

Cualquier cosa que no sea un numero, regresa TRUE

PERO debes de tener en cuenta la coerción, si tu le pasas true lo convierte a 1 entonces `isNaN(true) regresa false` porque es como si hicieras `isNaN(1)` y pregunta.

¿1 no es en numero? Responde falso 1 si es un número

Lo mismo con `2,3,4,5,6...`. La coerción de datos entra en escena  y antes de hacer la comparación lo "convierte" los datos en números y después compara

Entonces tu función quiero hacer una función que permita saber si una variable es numérica o no. Retornando true si lo es, y false si no. El problema está en que no sé cómo hacer para que en el caso que se utilicen variables booleanas retornen false.

```
function isNumber(d) {
  return d === Number(d) // De esta manera no existe la coercion de datos haces que lo que se compara tiene que ser igual valor y tipo 
}
```

```
function isNumber(d) {
  return d == Number(d) // Con doble '=' si existe la coerción ya decides tu que te conviene  
}
```

Cualquier duda me la dejas en los comentarios, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Eso se debe a la [coercion de javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/coercion)

Puede usar una expresión de evaluación `true/fase`, usando el operador [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/typeof) de esta manera si el "tipo de.." variable a evaluar es de tipo `number` devuelve `true`, otro caso devuelve `false`

```js
function comparar(variable){
  return typeof variable == 'number' 
}
console.log(comparar(5)); // true
console.log(comparar("hola")); // false 
console.log(comparar(true)); //false
```

Answer (score 1):

Una versión más robusta sería combinar [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/isNaN) junto con [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/typeof) para poder determinar si el valor ingresado sea un [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number)

```js
function esUnNumero(input) {
  return !isNaN(input) && typeof input === 'number';
}


console.log(esUnNumero(5));
console.log(esUnNumero("hola"));
console.log(esUnNumero(true));
console.log(esUnNumero('5'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function isNumeric(variable){
    return !isNaN(parseInt(variable));
}
```

Hola, lo que podes hacer es parsear la variable que se recibe por parámetro a un int ( transformar a Int) y utilizar la función isNaN para ver si el resultado de ese parseo no es un numero, isNaN se encarga de decirte si la variable no es un numero por lo tanto retorna true si no lo es , y false si efectivamente es un numero,por lo tanto tu quieres la negación del retorno de isNaN por ende agregamos la negación.

Esta funcion te sirve para saber si un dato es numérico o no.

Espero te haya ayudado , saludos

Answer (score 1):

Una función robusta y reducida

```js
function isNumber(n) {
  return typeof n == 'number';
}


console.log(isNumber(5));
console.log(isNumber("hola"));
console.log(isNumber(true));
console.log(isNumber('5'));
```

> El operador typeof se usa en cualquiera de los siguientes modos:
>
> ***typeof operando***
> ***typeof (operando)*** 
> El operador typeof devuelve una    cadena que indica el tipo del operando sin evaluarlo.
> operando es la    cadena, variable, palabra clave u objeto para el que
> se devolverá su    tipo. Los paréntesis son opcionales.

Puedes mirar la documentación desde este enlace:
[Typeof - Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/typeof)